# Implementing a pre commit dialog using tsvn:userdirproperties

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

As part of TortoiseSVN 1.8+ we can now use both `tsvn:userfileproperties` and `tsvn:userdirproperties` containing a newline
separated list of custom properties.

You can also specify whether a custom dialog is used to add/edit your property. TortoiseSVN offers four different dialogs, depending on the type of your property.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find a working example of how to set these properties.

I've set `tsvn:userdirproperties` to the following value:

```
my:build_trigger=state;Do you want to trigger a manifest build or flush the caches?(Skip;0;Rebuild;1;Build & Flush;2)
```

However no dialog is ever shown after any commits.

See [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-tsvn-props) for incomplete examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood usage of  tsvn: custom properties and editors

1. Custom property works as any other Subversion property: it's just additional attribute with some data, stored in repository
2. Custom editor invoked only and if "Edit" button pressed in properties window of TortoiseSVN interface

Also, **you can't change any data**, associated with transaction (and properties **is** part of transaction-data) in pre-commit hook. You can only **get value** of property (`svnlook pg`), which have to be defined before